# jQuery Exclusive OR

Tags: javascript, jquery, xor

I'm trying to work out a way to find elements with jQuery but ignore those where a container is nested. In the following example I need to select the second 'findMe' but not the first. There can be many zones, anchors and other containers in between but only two levels of zones. The simplest example is:

```
<div class="zone">
    <div class="zone">
        <a class="findMe"></a>
    </div>
    <a class="findMe"></a>
</div>
```

ie: I'm looking for something like an exclusive OR:

```
$allZoneAnchors = $('.zone a');
$nestedAnchors = $('.zone .zone a');
//Then somehow XOR $allZoneAnchors and $nestedAnchors
```

jQuery `.filter` looks interesting but you use it to

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector...

when what I want is to **Reduce the set of matched elements ('.zone a') to those that DO NOT match the selector ('.zone .zone a')**

eg:

```
$('.zone a').filterOutThingsThatMatch('.zone .zone a')
```

.not() doesn't seem to allow me to do the "not things that have a nested container" requirement.

Comment: Using a negation in your .filter() wouldn't work ? (.filter(function() { ... !== ... }

Comment: This does not actually appear to be an *exclusive or* situation, but simply and-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a second test of the nested state in a `not`:

```
$anchors = $('.zone a').not('.zone .zone a');
```

Which literally says "find my all anchors under zone classes, but not if the anchor is under a zone class which is under a zone class". This version will work for any depth or even if there are other divs between the zone levels.

If you know they are fixed depths this *might* be a little faster:

```
$anchors = $('.zone > a').not('.zone > .zone > a');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly you can use single CSS selector:

```
 var $nestedAnchors  = $(':not(.zone) .zone a');
```

You will match all `.zones` that are not under another `.zone`

`:not(.zone)` is a short cut of `*:not(.zone)` so any element but not '.zone'

Or jQuery `.not()`

```
var $('.zone a').not('.zone .zone a');
```

Because complexity of selector jQuery solution might be significantly faster.